# How to keep only one edit form open at a time in a composable function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am showing a list of rows with one word in it, inside a LazyColumn. On clicking the row, an edit form opens. The data is coming from a room database.

Since the row is on a separate composable function, I can open many different edit forms together (one in each row). But I want to show only one edit form in the whole list at a time. If I click one row to open an edit form, the rest of the open forms on the other rows should be closed. How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
    val words: List<Word> by wordViewModel.allWords.observeAsState(listOf())

    var newWord by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
        ) {
            items(words) { word ->
                WordItemLayout(
                    word = word,
                    onSaveUpdatedWord = { onUpdateWord(it) },
                    onTrashClicked = { onDeleteWord(it) }
                )
            }
        }
```

```
@Composable
fun WordItemLayout(word: Word, onSaveUpdatedWord: (Word) -> Unit, onTrashClicked: (Word) -> Unit) {
    var showEditForm by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var editedWord by remember { mutableStateOf(word.word) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant)
                .padding(vertical = 12.dp, horizontal = 24.dp)
                .clickable {
                    showEditForm = !showEditForm
                    editedWord = word.word
                },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_star), contentDescription = null)
            Text(
                text = word.word,
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
            )
            // Delete Button
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    showEditForm = false
                    onTrashClicked(word)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Word deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                modifier = Modifier.size(12.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Delete,
                    contentDescription = "Delete Word",
                    tint = Color.White
                )
            }
        }

        // word edit form
        if (showEditForm) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
            ) {
                TextField(
                    value = editedWord,
                    onValueChange = { editedWord = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor = Color.White) // TextField Background Color
                )
                // Update Button
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        val updatedWord: Word = word

                        if (updatedWord.word != editedWord.trim()) {
                            updatedWord.word = editedWord.trim()
                            onSaveUpdatedWord(updatedWord)
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Word updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }

                        showEditForm = false
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Done, contentDescription = "Update Word")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach: In your view model, declare an `openRowIndex` state (this will store the index of the opened row, you can initialize it to -1 for example).
Define a method that can change this state, for example `updateOpenRowIndex`

I'm not sure what kind of state holder you are using in your view model. I will use `StateFlow` for this answer. In your view model declare the new state and method:

```
private val _openRowIndex = MutableStateFlow(-1)
val openRowIndex: StateFlow<Int> = _openRowIndex

fun updateOpenRowIndex(updatedIndex: Int) {
   _openRowIndex.value = updatedIndex
}
```

For each row compisable, pass in the `index` of it inside the `LazyColumn`. You can get the indices using the `itemsIndexed` method. Also collect your `openRowIndex`, and pass that to the composable as well. Pass in also the method that updates the open row index:

```
itemsIndexed(words) { index, word ->
    //get the current opened row state and collect it (might look different for you if you are not using StateFlow):
    val openRowIndex = wordViewModel.openRowIndex.collectAsState()
    WordItemLayout(
        word = word,
        onSaveUpdatedWord = { onUpdateWord(it) },
        onTrashClicked = { onDeleteWord(it) },
        index = index, //new parameter!
        openRowIndex = openRowIndex.value //new parameter!
        onUpdateOpenedRow = wordViewModel::updateOpenRowIndex //new parameter!
    )

}
```

Now, in the row composable, simply check if the `index` and `openRowIndex` match, and display an opened row only if they match. Now to update the open row: make the `Row` clickable, and on click use view models `updateOpenRowIndex` method to update state to `index`. Compose will handle the rest and recompose when the state changes with the newly opened row!

```
fun WordItemLayout(
   word: Word,
   onSaveUpdatedWord: (Word) -> Unit,
   onTrashClicked: (Word), -> Unit,
   index: Int, //new parameters
   openRowIndex: Int,
   onUpdateOpenedRow: (Int) -> Unit
) {
   if(index == openRowIndex) {
      //display this row as opened
   } else {
      //display this row as closed
   }
}
```

As I said, make the row clickable and call the update function:

```
Row(
   modifier = Modifier.clickable {
      onUpdateOpenedRow(index)
      //additional instructions for what to happen when row is clicked...
   }
   //additional row parameters...
)
```